# How to add more items to a navbar button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm a beginner at bootstrap. Please bear with me.

How do I add more items to the button that appears on smaller screen sizes in the following code? Right now, the nav links are the content of the button. I would like to have more items that appear in the list when the button appears.

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Nav Bar</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
       </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Emergency</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Skip to Content</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

The fiddle is below:

http://jsfiddle.net/2sf7p510/

Thank you so much for your assistance.

**edit** - sorry, I gave the wrong jsfiddle link. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/8uJVN/143/

All you have to do is hide the list-item(s) in all screen-size except the one where you want it to appear:

```
<li class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg"><a href="#">Another Mobile Item</a></li>
```

Comment: wow, thanks so much! As soon as I reach the proper rep, I will upvote your answer! You're a big help Andrew! (btw, how can I raise my rep? I'm new here)

Comment: Glad I could help Skala :) And you can answer questions, add proper tags to other people's questions, ask questions that can get an upvote, etc to raise your rep.